# Not able to secure wordpress website on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have tried to secure my wordpress website hosted on AWS EC2 instance but after following many tutorials on Youtube still not able to do it

Steps I followed

1. EC2 Instance configured with WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic-6.4.2-8-
   r11 on Debian 11-AutogenByAWSMP--2
2. Loadbalancer configured
3. Loadbalancer added to EC2 instance
4. Created SSL certificate with ACM
5. Used Route 53 and changed nameservers in Godaddy
6. Created https listener with port and instance port of 443
7. Create Route 53 SSL certificate records
8. Used the security group created by WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic-
   6.4.2-8-r11 on Debian 11-AutogenByAWSMP--2
9. Used Security policy for ELB - ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08

and then still the website is not showing that it is secured
What shall i do about it?

Comment: What is the nature of the SSL error you get? It should give a reason. No certificate? Expired certificate? Doesn't match the site name?

Comment: @ceejayoz Connection is not secure , this the message i get in the address bar of the website

Comment: That message comes with additional details somewhere; on the error screen, or by clicking the message. Give us the domain, or put it in https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [configured Site name](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/) since you're using Bitnami AMI on an EC2 instance, you can SSH to the server. Since you're running only one ec2 instance and using the ELB just to use AWS Certificate Manager SSL certificate its better to move to Cloudflare, you can ditch ACM, ELB and Route53, move to Cloudflare and use a SSL certificate for free.